# validate_on_submit (flask-wtf) not working

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

I'm working on a sign-up page. The problem is that even if I submit `new_user` data, it won't store the `new_user` data in database and returns `users/signup.html` instead.
I believe [validate_on_submit](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/quickstart/) somehow causes the problem here. How can I store `new_user` data correctly?

#### users_bp.py

```py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user
from flask import redirect, render_template, request, flash
from flask import url_for
from flask_login import LoginManager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


@user.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        nickname = form.nickname.data
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            return render_template('users/login.html')

        new_user = User(email=email, nickname=nickname,
                        password=generate_password_hash('password', method='sha256'))

        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('home.html')
    return render_template('users/signup.html', form=form)
```

#### user_form.py

```py
from flask.app import Flask
from flask.templating import render_template
from wtforms import TextAreaField, StringField, Form, SelectField, SubmitField, PasswordField, DateField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from werkzeug.utils import redirect

class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    nickname = StringField('nickname')
    email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    recaption = RecaptchaField()
    send = SubmitField('submit')
```

#### users/signup.html

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="info-container">
    <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
        <h2 class="title">新規登録</h2>
        <div class="sign-description login-description">アカウントをお持ちの方はこちらから<a
                href="{{url_for('user.login')}}">ログイン</a>してください
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form action="" id="SignupForm" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group m-5">
        {{ form.nickname.label() }}
        {{ form.nickname(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.nickname.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.nickname.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-5">
        {{ form.email.label() }}
        {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.email.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-5">
        {{ form.password.label() }}
        {{ form.password(class='form-control') }}
        {% if form.password.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {{ form.send(class='btn btn-outline-dark mb-5 form-control') }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It is possible that `validate_on_submit` fails. Use `form.errors` to find out if there are errors with your form submission. And perhaps add your form template to your question. You can simply add: `{{ form.errors }}` in your page signup.html.

Comment: Hi @Anonymous. Thank you for the suggestion! I've added 'users/signup.html'.

Answer (score 0):

One guess: the problem could be the missing **captcha**, which is defined in your form model. If any of the requirements in your form class is not satisfied then `validate_on_submit` should fail. But you are not handling that condition.

Use `form.errors` to spit out validation errors if any...

I guess you are using Bootstrap, personally I use something like this in my form templates:

```
{% if form.is_submitted() and form.errors|count > 0 %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ form.errors|count }} error(s):
    <ul>
    {% for field_name, field_errors in form.errors|dictsort if field_errors %}
        {% for error in field_errors %}
            <li>{{ form[field_name].label }}: {{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

This will show a red box listing the form errors (if any).

If the form does not validate you need to tell the user somehow.